# Checking that this Proof by Induction is Correct

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

This is just to check that I got this proof correct. Also is my notation acceptable or do I have to redefine everything using the correct symbols from definition of mathematical induction? Thank you for reading

(2.4) Prove that $f(n) = g(n)\space \forall n\in \mathbb N$, $f(n)=1^3+2^3+...+n^3$ and $g(n)= (1+2+...+n)^2$

1. Let $h(n)=1+2+...+n$
   $\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=1+2+...+n+(n+1)$
   $\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=h(n)+(n+1)$
2. Let $t(n)= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$
   $\space\Rightarrow t(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$
3. Let $n=1,$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(1)=1\text{ ; }t(1)=\frac{1^2+1}{2}=1$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(1)=t(1)\text{ when }n=1$$
4. Suppose $h(n)=t(n)$ $ n\in \mathbb N$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(n)+(n+1)=f(n)+(n+1)$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=\frac{n^2+n}{2}+(n+1)\text{ By (1)}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=\frac{n^2+n+2n+2}{2}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow h(n+1)=t(n+1)\text{ By (2)}$$
5. Thus by (3), (4), and Priniciple of Mathematical Induction, $h(n)=t(n)$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N$
6. Let $f(n)=1^3+2^3+...+n^3$
   $\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=1^3+2^3+...+n^3+(n+1)^3$
   $\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=f(n)+(n+1)^3$
7. Let $g(n)= (1+2+...+n)^2$
   $\space\Rightarrow g(n)= (1+2+...+n)^2=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{2^2}=\frac{n^2(n^2+2n+1)}{4}=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} \text{ By (5)}$
   $\space\Rightarrow g(n+1)= \left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{2^2}=\frac{(n^2+2n+1)(n^2+4n+4)}{2^2}=\frac{(n^4+4n^3+4n^2+2n^3+8n^2+8n+2n^2+4n+4)}{4}=\frac{(n^4+6n^3+13n^2+12n+4)}{4}$
8. Suppose $n=1$,
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(1)=(1)^3=1\text{ ; }g(1)=(1)^2=1$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(1)=g(1)\text{ when }n=1$$
9. Suppose $f(n)=g(n)$ $ n\in \mathbb N$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n)+(n+1)^3=g(n)+(n+1)^3$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}+(n+1)^3\text{ By (6)}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2+4(n+1)^3}{4}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2+4n^3+12n^2+12n+4}{4}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=\frac{n^4+6n^3+13n^2+12n+4}{4}$$
   $$\space\Rightarrow f(n+1)=g(n+1)\text{ By (7)}$$
   Thus by (6), (7), and Priniciple of Mathematical Induction, $f(n)=g(n)$ $\forall n\in \mathbb N$

Comment: It's a bit verbose but it should work

Comment: In steps 4. and 9. you assume that the statement is true "for all positive integers" $n$. This is incorrect. The idea of induction is to assume that it  is true "for some" positive integer $n$ and prove that the statement is true for $n+1$. Combining this argument with the base case ($n=1$) makes sure that all positive integers are covered .

Comment: Fixed the "for all positive integers". That was just me being copy and pasting haphazardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof works for the most part, but if I really had to nitpick and criticize your proof, I would suggest the following improvements (in no order of importance):

1. Clarify whether you are using weak induction or strong induction.
2. In $(4)$, you say $h(n) = t(n), \forall n\in\mathbb N$. If that is the case, there is nothing to prove, right? The way (weak) induction works is that you would assume $h(n) = t(n)$ for **some** $n \in \mathbb N$, and then show $h(n+1) = t(n+1)$. If you are able to do so, you can **deduce** $h(n) = t(n), \forall n\in\mathbb N$ - but to start with that as an assumption is absurd.
3. Though you do not need to, if you were to use strong induction for the step above, the induction hypothesis would require you to assume $h(n) = t(n), \forall n < k$. In the induction step, you would show $h(k) = t(k)$ and **deduce** $h(n) = t(n), \forall n\in\mathbb N$.
4. In general, it is best to separate your induction proof into several parts: (i) check the **base case(s)** (ii) state the **induction hypothesis**, and if it is *weak or strong* (iii) work out the **induction step** and arrive at the conclusion.
5. Your notation is fine, I have seen such induction proofs in many places. If you had to be really formal, you could define use terminology such as "suppose $P(k)$ is true for $k\in \mathbb N$", then show $P(k+1)$, etc. for appropriate statement $P(k)$. A statement, after all, is well-defined in logical terms. In your case, first-order logic is sufficient - which gives you access to quantifiers $\forall, \exists$.

P.S. I see that you've edited your post, so my comments (2) and (3) may no longer be relevant. However, I'm still leaving them here in case they help.